# Adding new garage building. Adding a new main panel from the meter to it. Complication is I want to feed power to new building via a manual transfer

Tags: electrical

Can power from the house main panel be sent via a manual transfer switch when my whole house generator kicks in?  The generator is only tied to the house panel.
The house panel is 200 amps and the new building will be 150 amps. The power company installed a 320 service to my meter.  There’s an automatic transfer switch from the generator to the main panel.

I want to put a 150 amp breaker in the house panel to only feed the building if the meter is dead.  It would go to the manual transfer switch to the new building.  If the new building panel is wired as a main panel straight to the meter 99% of the time, when the power is supplied from the generator would that make it a sub-panel?  Do I have a problem with what I’m trying to do?

Comment: What loads in the garage are you trying to provide standby power to?  Also, are you deadset on having the generator back up the whole house, or is having a dedicated subpanel for the standby loads in the house an option?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Generator for the whole house needed for sure.  Load for the garage 220 stuff: 50 amp welder and plasma cutter, 30 amp compressor, air/electric heat, water heater, car lift.   I would just have the garage panel come off the meter as a main panel also, but need lights out there if the power has gone out.

Comment: How many square feet is the garage? Also, how big is the generator, how big is the house, and what sort of heavy appliance loads (range, dryer, water heater, AC/heat) are we looking at here?